# How to access the name canvas to MainPage from another class

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8.1

I'm C# newbie. I want to access my Canvas in MainPage.xaml from class CS_Line, but i can't do it. How to call the name's canvas in class CS_Line.cs.

MainPage.xaml:

`<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="573" Margin="154,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="913" Background="White"/>
    </Grid>`

in CS_Line.cs:

```
class CS_Line
{
    //attribute
    InkManager _inkKhaled = new Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkManager();

    private uint _penID;
    private uint _touchID;
    private Point _previousContactPt;
    private Point currentContacPt;
    private double x1;
    private double y1;
    private double x2;
    private double y2;

    //method
    private void MyCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(MyCanvas);  *//====>>>>> can't access the MyCanvas*
        _previousContactPt = pt.Position;

        PointerDeviceType pointerDevType = e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType;
        if (pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Pen ||
            pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse &&
            pt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            _inkKhaled.ProcessPointerDown(pt);
            _penID = pt.PointerId;

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        else if (pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Touch)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: you mean you cannot access  MyCanvas. in MainPage.xaml.cs file?

Comment: Hoe you added the MyCanvas_PointerPressed event?

Comment: You need to hook that event from your xaml

Comment: Yes, i can not access MyCanvas in MainPage.xaml.cs file from my class !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `MyCanvas` from `sender`.

```
private void MyCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas myCanvas = sender as Canvas; // Here's your MyCanvas object
    PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas);
    _previousContactPt = pt.Position;
```